# Update a draw in a Java Canvas

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to make an application in which I can draw a path on a canvas. The problem is that I have to update this canvas continuously.

Currently I'm able to do it, but I have to redraw all the path every time and so I have to store all the points in memory. I would prefer to simply update the draw by adding a new point.

Is it possible?

Currently my code is:

```
public class MyCanvas extends Canvas{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public MyCanvas(){}
        public void paint(Graphics graphics){
            super.paint(graphics);
            graphics.setColor(Color.green);
            // points is an ArrayList of Point2D
            for (Iterator iterator = points.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
               Point2D point2d = (Point2D) iterator.next();
               graphics.fillOval((int)((canvas.getWidth()/2.0) + point2d.getX()), (int)((canvas.getHeight()/2.0) + point2d.getY()), 5, 5);
            }   
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT

This is the current solution:

```
PanelCanvas canvasPanel;
...
public void drawCircle(int x, int y){
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.green);
    g2d.setBackground(Color.white);
    g2d.fillOval((int)((panelCanvas.getWidth() / 2.0) + x/10.0), (int)((panelCanvas.getHeight() / 2.0) + y/10.0), 5, 5);
    panelCanvas.repaint();
}

public class CanvasPanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){
        super.paintComponents(graphics);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g2d.setBackground(Color.white);
        g2d.drawImage(bufferedImage, null, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in this millennium, are you coding using AWT components?  Most people that did use them have forgotten how.  Also, if it is pure AWT, why did you add the [tag:swing] tag?  Questions within questions..

Comment: @AndrewThompson The canvas is embedded in a Swing GUI. What do you suggest for replacing AWT.Canvas? Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping to avoid specific code on this question, but.. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I fixed it byt drawing a white rectangle: `g2d.fillRect(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw the points (whatever) to a `BufferedImage`.  During `paint()`, draw the `BufferedImage`.

---

Note though, that the JRE can draw thousands of objects in paint without any visual artifacts or slow-down.

---

> The canvas is embedded in a Swing GUI. What do you suggest for replacing AWT.Canvas?

[`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) for complete custom rendering, [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) for custom rendering combined with components.  It sounds like the `JComponent` would be better suited to this use-case.

For either of those, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead of `paint(Graphics)`.  The rest of the advice is the same.

Comment: Your solution works. Only one problem, the image background is black. I tries to set the image background and also the panel background but didn't work. See the new implementation in the question. Thanks